# Access data() object from Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api

(For a currency converter)

I need to access a object like this:

```
rates:
  AUD: 1.708562
  SGD: 1.546211
```

I get these rates from an API but they don't come in order. i.e if I ask for USD to GBP it will display GBP first. So I need a way to get the requested symbols to get the values.

I tried this:

```
const from = res.rates.this.convertFrom.symbol;
// -----AND-----
const fromSymbol = this.convertFrom.symbol;
const from = res.rates.fromSymbol.toString();
```

Which didn't work

Link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-rain-mtv4b?file=/App.vue)

PS: `this.convertFrom.symbol` returns the input from the user. In this case, it's `symbol: 'SGD'`

Comment: Hope this works: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-rain-mtv4b?file=/App.vue)

Comment: Can you access the sandbox @palaѕн?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you have setup data like:

```
convertFrom: {
    currency: "GBP: British Pounds",
    symbol: "",
    amount: 0
},
  convertTo: {
    currency: "USD: United States Dollar",
      symbol: "",
        amount: 0
  }
```

Next, inside `convert()` method you have also set the currency symbol like:

```
this.convertFrom.symbol = this.convertFrom.currency.toString().split(":")[0];
this.convertTo.symbol = this.convertTo.currency.toString().split(":")[0];
```

So, now values of `convertFrom.symbol` and `convertTo.symbol` are:

```
this.convertFrom.symbol => "GBP"
this.convertTo.symbol => "USD"
```

You have also mentioned `fetch` response here is like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "base": "EUR",
    "rates": {
        "GBP": 0.869339,
        "USD": 1.0875
    }
}
```

Now, we easily access an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation. But as the object `rates` keys here are dynamic, we will need to use the bracket notation like:

```
const from = res.rates[this.convertFrom.symbol]
const to = res.rates[this.convertTo.symbol]
```

**Demo:**

```js
const res = {
  "success": true,
  "base": "EUR",
  "rates": {
    "GBP": 0.869339,
    "USD": 1.0875
  }
}

const data = {
  convertFrom: { symbol: "GBP" },
  convertTo: { symbol: "USD" }
}

const from = res.rates[data.convertFrom.symbol];
const to = res.rates[data.convertTo.symbol];

console.log('From:\t', from)
console.log('To:\t', to)
```

Comment: Yes Thanks!! I was tried `res.rates.[data.convertFrom.symbol]`... was so close. Thanks for the detailed response @palaѕн !